# How to replace an area chart with a line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, stacked-area-chart, area-chart

I'm very new to d3js and i'm trying to modify the example : https://blockbuilder.org/lorenzopub/9d030cdfe0f3564fd5d7b9047e440084.
I would like to replace the first area with a simple line plot. I changed only these lines of code:

```
//old: generators.local.area = d3.area(localTaxData).x(function(d){return generators.shared.x(d.year);})
//   .y0(function(d){return generators.federal.y(0);}).y1(function(d){return generators.federal.y(d.taxRate);})
//   .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

generators.local.area = d3.line(localTaxData).x(function(d){return generators.shared.x(d.year);})
  .y(function(d){return generators.federal.y(d.taxRate);}).curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
```

but I get:
[image]
can some one help me?

[image]

Comment: Set `fill: none;` to the path.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for the reply. I tryied but I get no curves at all...

Comment: Did you set the `stroke`? The default value for SVG is `none`, so you have to set something (like `stroke: black;`).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado NO! now i set it and it works! Thanks a lot! Nevertheless, it seems that the data for the graph in which I use d3.line are not displayed correctly. I think there is a problem with the scale but I'm not able to figure out such a problem. See the picture I added...